# Didselect method of fs-Calendar results in showing wrong date?

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm working on FSCalenadr but didSelect event fires when I select particular date. For example, if I select 9 Nov 2019 it shows selected date 2019-11-30 18:30:00 +0000

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    print("selected date \(date)")

    setCalendarDate(pDate: date)
}
```